# Reinforcement Learning: definition of expected discounted return in Sutton and Barto's book

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am going through Sutton and Barto's book on reinforcement learning
http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf

In the book pg 44 equation 3.8, the authors define expected discounted return as

$G_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma R_{t+2} + \ldots$

1. Why is it called "expected" return? Does it have anything to do with expectation? i.e., can I rewrite $G_t$ in terms of expectation?

   Is $R_{t+1}$ a random variable? (the authors defined on page 38, top of the page near the diagram, that $R_{t+1}$ is a real number, but a random variable is a function, no?)
2. Why does the expected discounted return start with $t+1$?

In my opinion, this causes a problem later on when the authors define the optimal Q value in terms of the "Bellman optimality equation", pg 51, equation 3.20

$q^\star(s,a) = \mathbb{E}[R_{t+1} + r \max_{a^\prime} q^\star(S_{t+1}, a^\prime)| S_t = s, A_t = a]$

The optimal q value should have the intuitive definition as the reward at the CURRENT time step $t$ plus the optimal expected discounted reward. So that $R_{t+1}$ should be re-written as $R_{t}$ should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why is it called "expected" return? Does it have anything to do with expectation? i.e., can I rewrite $G_t$ in terms of expectation?

No. This is just a problem with parsing the English, where it is ambiguous.

"The expected return $G_t$" can mean two things in normal English:

- "Expected return" is represented by $G_t$
- "Return" is represented by $G_t$ and we are interested in its expected value

The sentence in Sutton and Barto and equation 3.8 are using the second meaning.

$G_t$ is a random variable, and does not itself include any expected value. There is a difference between $G_t$, which is a random variable with a distribution and $\mathbb{E}[G_t]$. In reinforcement learning, discovering the value of $\mathbb{E}[G_t]$, under some initial conditions and constraints, is often of interest. For instance the state value function $v_{\pi}(s)$ can be written $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[G_t | S_t = s]$ i.e. the expected return given starting in state $s$ and following policy $\pi$.

> Is $R_{t+1}$ a random variable?

Yes.

> but a random variable is a function, no?

[No](http://www.statisticshowto.com/random-variable/). The random variable is a placeholder for general case of "the actual value can/will be sampled at some point", and is used to write formulae that would apply regardless of outcome. Or it can be viewed more formally as a (potentially unknown) distribution of values, and all equations as manipulations of those distributions.

> 2. Why does the expected discounted return start with $t+1$?

This is just a convention. You will find other sources that use the convention that reward $r$ from taking action $a$ in state $s$ at time $t$ is noted $r_{t}$ (random variable placeholder $R_{t}$). This changes all the related equations as you would expect, but makes no difference to any results or behaviour of algorithms.

The convention is based on the feedback loop - the reward and next state are received *after* taking an action, and often at the same time, so it is natural to assign them to the same time step index.

> The optimal q value should have the intuitive definition as the reward at the CURRENT time step t plus the optimal expected discounted reward.

For the Q function to be useful, it has to predict *consequences* of an action in a specific state. Regardless of the indexing convention in use, that means ignoring rewards that have already been received (including any for arriving in a particular state), and only counting the rewards received *after* taking the action.